# SearchBarから入力したテキストに部分一致したデータを表示したい

Tags: swift, realm

SwiftでRealmを使ってデータベースに文字を保存し、テーブルビューで表示をすることまではできたのですが、searchbarを使って検索で一部一致したらテーブルビューに反映するためにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。
Todoリストのようなものを下記のサイトを手本にしてつくっている感じです。
ネットを探すと検索条件をResults().filter(_:...)メソッドでオブジェクトを取得してるのを多く見ますが、サーチバーで記入した文字をどのようにfilterで記述するのか、またそれをテーブルビューに反映させるにはどうしたらいいのか、わからないところが多々あります。

理解が乏しい部分も多いと思いますが、考え方を教えていただければ幸いです。

http://qiita.com/g08m11/items/8d4f7e82e89195ff301c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、手本としている記事のコードは`toDoItems`を計算済みプロパティとしてるのがよくないです。Realmの`Results`は自動的に最新の状態に更新されるので、検索条件が同じなら毎回取得する必要はありません。

下記のコードでは`var toDoItems: Results<ToDo>?`を通常のプロパティに直しました。

Realmのデータを条件で絞り込むには`filter()`メソッドを利用します。
検索バーに入力された文字列を使って部分一致で検索するには`BEGINSWITH`（前方一致）、`ENDSWITH`（後方一致）、`CONTAINS`（部分一致）を使います。

```
toDoItems = realm
    .objects(ToDo)
    .filter("name BEGINSWITH %@", searchText)
```

上記は`ToDo`のオブジェクトを`name`プロパティの前方一致で検索する例です。

UISearchBarの入力をトリガーにして検索を実行し、画面に反映するには、UISearchBarDelegateのテキストが入力されたら呼ばれるメソッドで処理をします。
TableViewのデータソースに使っている`Results`オブジェクトを、入力された文字列を使って検索したものに更新し、表示に反映させるためにTableViewをリロードします。

下記はコードの例です。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var todoNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var toDoItems: Results<ToDo>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let realm = try! Realm()
        toDoItems = realm.objects(ToDo)
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        if searchText.isEmpty {
            toDoItems = realm.objects(ToDo)
        } else {
            toDoItems = realm
                .objects(ToDo)
                .filter("name BEGINSWITH %@", searchText)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます！おかげさまで無事にデータ表示をすることができました＾＾この調子で勉強させていただきます！ありがとうございました。

Comment: すみません、こちらとは別件でfilterについてもう１つ伺いたいのですが、filterで検索条件を指定する際に、設定したい値を前の画面からセグエで受け取った値を使いたい場合はどうしたらいいのでしょうか。メンバ変数を直接入力してもダメだったので、、何か変換が必要、もしくは条件指定できないのでしょうか？

Comment: @y.you 新しい質問を投稿してください。サイトの方針でもあり、他の人のためでもあります。それと、この質問は解決したなら回答を承認してください。そうしないと、いつまでも未解決の質問で定期的に上がってきてしまいます。

Comment: 失礼しました！わからないことだったので指摘助かります。＾＾